# Google recaptcha API POST request giving 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: php, post, recaptcha, http-status-code-403, fsockopen

POST request giving forbidden error for below request.

Code from Google Code archive https://storage.googleapis.com/google-code-archive-downloads/v2/code.google.com/recaptcha/recaptcha-php-1.11.zip

**Function Call as below**

```
$response = _recaptcha_http_post (RECAPTCHA_VERIFY_SERVER, "/recaptcha/api/siteverify",
                                      array (
                                             'privatekey' => $privkey,
                                             'remoteip' => $remoteip,
                                             'response' => $response
                                             ) + $extra_params
                                      );
```

**Function is Below**

```
function _recaptcha_http_post($host, $path, $data, $port = 80) {

    $req = _recaptcha_qsencode ($data);

    $http_request  = "POST $path HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    $http_request .= "Host: $host\r\n";
    $http_request .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;\r\n";
    $http_request .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n";
    $http_request .= "User-Agent: reCAPTCHA/PHP\r\n";
    $http_request .= "\r\n";
    $http_request .= $req;

    echo "HTTP_Request - ";
    echo $http_request;

    $response = '';
    if( false == ( $fs = @fsockopen($host, $port, $errno, $errstr, 10) ) ) {
            die ('Could not open socket');
    }

    fwrite($fs, $http_request);

    while ( !feof($fs) )
            $response .= fgets($fs, 1160); // One TCP-IP packet
    fclose($fs);
    echo "HTTP_Response - ";
    echo $response;
    $response = explode("\r\n\r\n", $response, 2);


    return $response; }
```

**Request and Response as Below**

**HTTP_Request =** 
POST /recaptcha/api/siteverify HTTP/1.0 Host: www.google.com Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; Content-Length: 418 User-Agent: reCAPTCHA/PHP privatekey=6LdWx7AUAAAAANcawRDmFaZ3mto2mR9BPxuO5Q7V&remoteip=91.75.176.244&response=03AOLTBLRSaTq0r_J2gVWzsmxtidDnGAIeIpfM8jga9qmMD9rfKFm-cymLoT6dWhJjAimn7RmPOx1IPTLoUeiAXS1m8qobI8Yk_kPtmPHRm17lxsFbOKMG6b5-nldm4sSNohW02zz9D0sDkymEnGWXej3bTczvv2ah1PePJCIBG-3Ae0IuJP2EwvD4AXtj5mFXZdomcBqe1zGLny4aiO6-KcRy73MRkvGLYxiWGd8BeV3wQvwTPJWhlsoAQjEtBqwFOnbc9ifeWGrMlXCkcXJRGJBsWUqKZ9VkqeKfs00O4RWN9TYDp7d1DGbQFdj7d5iUIpK4MIIRWJeE

**HTTP_Response =** 
HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date: Thu, 15 Aug 2019 07:30:28 GMT Expires: Thu, 15 Aug 2019 07:30:28 GMT Cache-Control: private, max-age=0 X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block Server: GSE Accept-Ranges: none Vary: Accept-Encoding

Comment: Out of curiosity. Why don't you use a request library like e.g. guzzle or curl? It helps a lot with correct request formatting

Comment: Above code is from PHP client library for reCAPTCHA in google code archive

Comment: I would strongly recommend finding a newer library to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

403 Error was due to outbound **https** connections blocked from the requesting server.
When https connection is allowed in server settings. Error went away.

Used below code instead of reachability library.

```
function isValid() {try {

    $url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
    $data = ['secret'   => 'YOUR SECRET KEY',
             'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
             'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']];

    $options = [
        'http' => [
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data) 
        ]
    ];

    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    return json_decode($result)->success;
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Exception";
    return null;
}
```

}