# reCaptcha enterprise assessment returns Forbidden

Tags: recaptcha-enterprise

Background - I'm implementing "reCAPTCHA Enterprise REST API, using API keys for authentication".  I created a project and a reCaptcha test key (site key) at https://console.cloud.google.com/security/recaptcha using localhost as domain but domain verification turned off for now (6L***...***vw). I create an API key at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials.

My javascript has this for my script loader

```
scripts = ["https://www.google.com/recaptcha/enterprise.js?render=6L***...***vw"];
loadScripts(0);
```

and then when you sign in it triggers this

```
var recaptchResponse;
grecaptcha.enterprise.ready(async () => {
    recaptchResponse = await grecaptcha.enterprise.execute('6L***...***vw', { action: 'LOGIN' });
    authSrv2.login(vm.emailAddress, vm.password, recaptchResponse, 'LOGIN').then(function (loginResult) {
...
```

which triggers an API call to my backend which is Web API in C# and runs RunAssessment

```
public class reCaptcha {
    public async Task<bool> RunAssessment(string token, string action) {
        // score based key, recaptcha key, enterprise key. site key
        string SiteKey = "6L***...***vw";
        string APIKey = "AI***...***So";

        string project = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("reCaptchaProject");
        string url = "https://recaptchaenterprise.googleapis.com/v1/projects/" + project + "/assessments?key=" + APIKey;
        string myJson = "{\"event\": { \"token\": \"" + token + "\", \"siteKey\": \"" + SiteKey + "\", \"expectedAction\": \"" + action + "\" } }";
        HttpResponseMessage response;
        using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
            try {
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(myJson, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).ConfigureAwait(false);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode) {
                    // TODO parse results
                    var dynamicObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(response.Content.ToString());
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                var y = ex;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

response always returns a 403 Forbidden
Any ideas?

UPDATE
From fiddler - request header
[image]

request json
[image]

Response json
[image]

Comment: Also tried this now using WebClient and same response - remote server returned forbidden

Comment: I've added some screen shots from fiddler

Comment: I have now verified this behavior on a different server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was able to make this work by manually adding the referer header

Answer (score 0):

As per [Afsal Meerankutty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57506366/google-recaptcha-api-post-request-giving-403-forbidden-error) from a previous post with the same error encountered, 403 error was due to network settings where outbound https connections from the requesting server were blocked. When the https connection was allowed, the error was fixed.

Here is a sample code they used:

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify';
$data = ['secret'   => 'YOUR SECRET KEY',
         'response' => $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'],
         'remoteip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']];

$options = [
    'http' => [
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data) 
    ]
];

$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
return json_decode($result)->success;
```

} catch (Exception $e) { echo "Exception"; return null; }

Comment: Thanks but I have now verified that the same thing happens on a different server with a different domain (not localhost) and a valid cert